# RSpec: Can't seem to stub ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, stub

I'm trying to write a test that computes the average of many db records without the overhead of actually reading/writing to the db.

Here is the method:

```
class Average::Route
  def self.daily_flight_count
    Route.active.map do |r|
      times = r.flights.select('distinct depart_time').count
      (times / 7.0).round
    end.average
  end
end
```

The method gets the number of unique depart times per day for all routes and averages it to get the average route's daily flight count.

I'm setting up my test like so:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Average::Route do
  describe '.daily_flight_count' do
    it 'returns the average daily flight count of all routes' do
      flights1 = (1..7).inject([]) do |arr, n|
        arr << double(Flight, depart_time: Time.now + n.days)
      end

      flights2 = (1..7).inject([]) do |arr, n|
        arr << double(Flight, depart_time: Time.now + n.days)
        arr << double(Flight, depart_time: Time.now + n.days)
      end

      r1 = double(Route, flights: flights1)
      r2 = double(Route, flights: flights2)

      allow(Route).to receive(:active).and_return([r1, r2])
      allow(flights1).to receive(:select).and_return(flights1.map(&:depart_time))
      allow(flights2).to receive(:select).and_return(flights2.map(&:depart_time))

      expect(Average::Route.daily_flight_count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

Based on how `r1` and `r2` are doubles of Route set to return arrays of Flight doubles, I ran into a problem since an array responds to `#select` differently than an ActiveRecord Relation (how it would really behave), so I tried to stub the `flights1` and `flights2` arrays to return their mapped depart times. However, when I run my test I still get this error:

```
Failures:

  1) Average::Route.daily_flight_count returns the average daily flight count of all routes
     Failure/Error: expect(Average::Route.daily_flight_count).to eq(1)
     ArgumentError:
       Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.
     # ./app/models/average/route.rb:14:in `block in daily_flight_count'
     # ./app/models/average/route.rb:13:in `map'
```

The stubs for `flights1` and `flights2` don't seem to be working. The error is still calling the ActiveRecord `#select` method on my array of doubles and failing because `Array#select` takes a block and my code gives it an argument (since in production the collection would be a Relation).

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the parameters you're expecting

```
 allow(flights1).to receive(:select).with('distinct depart_time').and_return(flights1.map(&:depart_time))
```